# How to update dateISO function in Jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

In its current state, the dateISO function in the Jquery validation plugin is as follows:

```
dateISO: function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}$/.test(value);
}
```

I have noticed that when a user enters a date like `1991-99-99`, it is seen  as a "valid date", when it obviously is not.

How would I change this code to have it validate that the month is in the range of `01-12` and the day is in the range of `1-31`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, good date validation is very difficult.  From **Time and the Art of Living** (as quoted in the GNU date documentation), I quote Robert Grudin:

> Our units of temporal measurement,
>   from seconds on up to months, are so
>   complicated, asymmetrical and
>   disjunctive so as to make coherent
>   mental reckoning in time all but
>   impossible. Indeed, had some
>   tyrannical god contrived to enslave
>   our minds to time, to make it all but
>   impossible for us to escape subjection
>   to sodden routines and unpleasant
>   surprises, he could hardly have done
>   better than handing down our present
>   system.

However, if you only want to accept dates in that YYYY-MM-DD format, the work gets a little easier.  How about something like:

```
dateISO: function(value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) return true;
  var regexp = new RegExp('^\d{4}[\/-](\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,2})$');
  var matches = regexp.exec(value);
  if (!matches) return false;
  if (matches[2] > 31) return false;

  if (matches[1] == 2 && matches[2] > 28) return false;
  if ((matches[1] == 1 || matches[1] == 3 || matches[1] == 5 || matches[1] == 7 || matches[1] == 8 || matches[1] == 10 || matches[1] == 12) && matches[2] > 30) return false;

  return true;
},
```

Comment: i get an error on the line "if(!matches[0]) return false";

Message: '0' is null or not an object

Comment: Good point.  It should simply be testing the result of `.exec()`.

Comment: This code doesnt work, but this does:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301466/whats-wrong-with-this-jquery-validation-code-regexp-execvalue